# nginx request redirected

Tags: nginx

I've noticed in my nginx `access.log` entries like this:

`XX.XX.XX.XX - - [05/Jan/2017:00:21:43 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "libwww-perl/6.05"`

This is weird because i've implemented GeoIP blocking in nginx, so only IP Adresses from my country and local network have access to my server. Other IPs should be "blocked" with HTTP status code 444. This GeoIP implementation should work, because I've tested it multiple times.

But why does nginx return 301 to this foreign IP Adress (not in my country)?

This is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    # enforce https
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    if ($lan-ip = yes) {
        set $allowed_country yes;
    }

    if ($allowed_country = no) {
        return 444;
    }

    root /var/www/html;

    # SSL Configuration
    # .
    # .
    # .
}
```

This is the GeoIP blocking party in `nginx.conf`:

```
geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;

map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country {
    default no;
    DE yes;
}

geo $lan-ip {
    default no;
    192.168.0.0/24 yes;
}
```

Comment: How is your GeoIP blocking implemented exactly? Have you checked the IP in question against exactly the same database you use for blocking?

Comment: I added the GeoIP blocking part of `nginx.conf` in the question! 

How can I check if the IP address is not in my country according to my local GeoIP database? The GeoIP database has the `.dat` extension.

Comment: Check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7399/ip-to-country-console-command and the documentation from the distributor of your database (probably maxmind) for how to query the database. And note that the database is not fully reliable. My guess is that nothing is wrong with your configuration but that the database reports this IP to be in your country.

Comment: According to GeoIP this IP is from the Netherlands. So it should have been blocked.

Comment: So you've checked against exactly the same database as your nginx uses? Since different providers have different databases with different errors it will not help if you checked against some other database.

Comment: Yes, I checked against my local `GeoIP.dat` which is used by nginx.

Comment: An `http` request will hit the first `server` block. Your GeoIP blocking is only applied after the `301` redirect, which is consistent with the logfile entry in your question.

Comment: @RichardSmith, so what should be chanced to avoid such `301` redirects and block them with `444`?

Comment: Another information: Only HTTPS port is opened on my router, so only HTTPS requests are accepted from the internet.

Comment: Nobody here with an answer?

Comment: Really nobody out there?

Comment: Still waiting for an expert out there ....

Comment: Again i had 20 of those requests within 40 minutes from the same ip address. There must be an expert out there ...